# Walls streaking

Tags: walls

We have been in our home almost 2 years (it was originally built early 2000s) and we keep noticing things wrong with the walls. Tonight we noticed these lines all over one of the walls in our daughter’s room. Does anyone know what this is or what is causing these lines? They don’t feel wet.[image]

Comment: Is it something to do with the finish of the paint itself, or does it seem like it is under the paint?  It could just be a sloppy roller paint job.

Comment: possibly crayon marks under the paint

Comment: It seems like something is bleeding through the paint. I would say moisture but it doesn’t feel damp and I’m not sure what around this wall would have moisture. The marks don’t rub off. Definitely not crayon or any other coloring utensil and she didn’t put anything on the wall.
I painted the walls myself, prepped them and applied the paint the same way I have in my previous 2 homes. I never had this happen so I would like to think it’s not my paint job. If it was the paint job wouldn’t it have shown around the time I painted it(2yrs ago)? These marks go across the entire wall.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are they on any other wall? Are they evenly spread across that wall, or only waist high or some other subsection of the wall? What's different about where they are? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: They aren’t evenly spread out but they go across the wall from one side to the other (just that wall) and all start around the same level about 6ft. It’s an inside wall between bedrooms. The wall that is on the other side in the other bedroom does not have these marks. It almost looks oily but when I wipe it- it doesn’t go away.

Comment: I think that the crayon comment was meant to mean crayon (or something) was UNDER the paint, as in the walls had something on them BEFORE you bought it, and that something is now bleeding through the paint that was put on afterward. That happens a lot if the marks are not properly sealed with the right kind of primer before painting. Often when someone is going to sell a house, they get a cheap paint job that just makes it look good enough for the sale.

Comment: At 6' off the ground, it's not as likely, but it could be from the daughter rubbing an eraser across the wall just for fun (or maybe she used a pencil to write on the wall, realized that was bad and erased the marks).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this wall was not properly primed before it was painted. The paint job is showing what is usually called *flashing*: delineated areas of the surface where the texture or appearance does not match the surrounding paint.

It appears you have a medium gloss paint. Unfortunately, gloss amplifies every little imperfection in the underlying surface and can make for some really nasty flashing. Larger walls, bright lighting (ie. sunlight), and very sharp lighting angles will make it even more noticeable.

It's a bit harder to say what is actually causing it. Some change in texture and composition from the rest of the underlying wall surface is causing the paint above it to dry differently (this is what primer will prevent, by sealing the old and creating a fresh, homogenous surface for the new paint).

My guess is that it's some drywall compound that was not adequately covered after the walls were finished. If that stuff gets applied at different thicknesses (which always happens, it is unavoidable), it acts like a sponge when any kind of water based paint gets applied over the top, sucking out the moisture and creating areas that dry differently. This can happen even after several layers of paint.

The best way to fix it would be to get a good oil based primer and go over the whole wall with at least one, and preferably two even coats. You must use oil based primer, so also plan for good ventilation and probably a respirator and goggles. Once the primer is dry, repaint in the same color and it should look a whole lot better. Most primer is white when you grab it off the shelf, but the store should be able to tint it closer to the top coat color so you won't need as many coats.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will definitely be following your instructions and get this fixed!

Comment: Yep, good luck! One other thing to keep in mind: if there are any surface irregularities (dents, scratches, odd textures, nail pops, etc....), deal with those before you prime. You'll never be able to put down enough primer/paint to hide that stuff (and it's really tempting to tell yourself that it's possible).